# List of selected element not correctly set using a thymeleaf checkbox

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my web page I want to display a list containing all natures and I want the selected ones to be set in a list.

My issue is that the list is correctly set in my list displayed but not in the list of selected elements : natures. Indeed, instead of the attribute String "nom" of my nature, it's its reference that is stored : `fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.Nature@19c4a02` by instance

Here is the checkbox display :

[image: checkbox display]

What I want : When I check by instance the 2 fist checkbox, I want to have in my controller the `List<Nature> natures` valued to

```
natures.get(0).nom = "bcmc_envtraco_out"
natures.get(0).routage = INSTANCE

natures.get(1).nom = "bcmc_medtab_out"
natures.get(1).routage = INSTANCE
```

When it worked before, the checkbox was a `list<String>`, I think the problem occured because I do something wrong using the `list<Nature>`.

Here is my relevant web page code :

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/bus/topologie}"
    th:object="${topologie}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="col-sm-10" th:if="!${#lists.isEmpty(allNature)}">
    <div th:each="nature : ${allNature}" class="checkbox">
        <label th:for="${#ids.next('nature')}"> 
         <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{natures}" th:value="${nature}" class="checkboxNature" />
         <span th:text="${nature.nom}" class="col-sm-5">...</span>
         <span th:text="${nature.routage.nom}" class="col-sm-5">...</span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

This code is interpreted like this (copy from the html code in chrome) :

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="nature1"> 
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxNature" value="fr.cnamts.navigo.domain.Nature@19c4a02" id="natures3" name="natures"><input type="hidden" name="_natures" value="on">
     <span class="col-sm-5">bcmc_trabcmreca_out</span>
     <span class="col-sm-7">Routage sur instance</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

The relevant code in my controller :

```
@ModelAttribute("allNature")
public List<Nature> getAllNatures(Topologie topologie) throws Exception
{
    return natureService.getNaturesByVersionCadre(topologie.getCadre(), topologie.getVersionCadre());
}
```

And the relevant code in my object "Topologie" :

```
public class Topologie {
    private List<Nature> natures = new ArrayList<Nature>();
```

And eventually the Nature Class :

```
public class Nature {

    @NotBlank
    private String nom;

    @NotNull
    private Routage routage;

    // @NotNull
    // private String typeCl;

    public enum Routage {
        INSTANCE("Routage sur instance", "^[A-Za-z0-9]{2}$ (instance)"), UCANSS(
                "Routage sur code UCANSS", "^[A-Za-z0-9]{2}$ (Code UCANSS)"), ACOSS(
                "Routage sur code ACOSS", "^[A-Za-z0-9]{2}$ (Code ACOSS)"), INSTANCE_MIAM(
                "Routage sur code instance MIAM", "^[A-Za-z0-9]{2}$ (instance)"), CODEREGIME_CODECAISSE(
                "Routage sur coderégime+code caisse",
                "^[0-9]{2}[0-9]{3}$  (Code régime code caisse)");

        private final String nomRoutage;
        // private final String codecle;
        private final String regExp;

        Routage(String nom, String regexp) {
            this.nomRoutage = nom;
            this.regExp = regexp;
        }

        public String getNom() {
            return nomRoutage;
        }

        public String getRegExp() {
            return regExp;
        }
    }

    public Nature(String nomNature) {
        nom = nomNature;
        // TODO à modifier une fois récup faite dans fichier zk
        routage = Routage.INSTANCE;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public Routage getRoutage() {
        // TODO à modifier une fois récup faite dans fichier zk
        if (routage == null) {
            routage = Routage.INSTANCE;
        }
        return routage;
    }

    public void setRoutage(Routage routage) {
        // TODO à modifier une fois récup faite dans fichier zk
        if (routage == null) {
            routage = Routage.INSTANCE;
        }
        this.routage = routage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your **th:value** attribute value to **${nature.nom}**

Just like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{natures}" th:value="${nature.nom}" class="checkboxNature" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: Okay, I checked it and the Thymeleaf should handle th:checked attribute by itself.
Then try to change th:value to th:value="${nature.nom}".

Comment: works great thanks. You can change your answer with this one and I will validate it ;)

Comment: Done :) I'm glad I could help you.