# How to save relations based on checkboxes using Theyleaf and Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot 1.5 with Thymeleaf 3.

Lets have many to many relation between entities `Place` and `Category`

```
public class Category extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
    private Set<Place> places;

}

public class Place extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "place_id"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="category_id"))
    private Set<Category> categories;

}
```

Now I want to list every category and allow user to select some categories. Selected categories should be added to `Place.categories` set (thus creating a relation)

How can I do that?

I have following `form` fragment:

```
<div th:fragment="services(selectedServices,allServices)">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select services</legend>
        <div class="checkbox" th:object="${selectedServices}" th:each="service : ${allServices}">
            <label> <input th:value="${service.id}" type="checkbox" /> <span th:text="${service.name}" th:remove="tag"> </span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Where I assumed that `allServices` is a result of `serviceRepository.findAll()` so simple list containing all services, and `selectedServices` would be a collection returned by `${place.services}` (effectively, selected categories)

This displays list just fine, but how to bind selection to my `place` entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct answer which I have found out short after submitting a question. Works more than good.

```
<div th:fragment="categories(place,allCategories)">
    <fieldset th:object="${place}" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('categories')} ? 'has-error' : _ ">
        <legend>Select categories</legend>
        <div class="checkbox" th:object="${place}" th:each="category : ${allCategories}">
            <label> <input th:value="${category.id}" th:field="*{categories}" type="checkbox" /> <span th:text="${category.name}" th:remove="tag"> </span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <span class="help-block" th:each="msg : ${#fields.errors('categories')}" th:text="${msg}">Some error message for this field</span>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like this:

```
<div class="checkbox" th:each="category : ${allCategories}"> 
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{categories}" th:value="${category.name}" class="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

Inside your form.

Please check also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845091/4491130

Comment: The only thing that is required here is to change value to `category.id` not `category.name`. I am upvoting because it is very close to correct answer. I am curious, should it work for other property then ID as well (does not work form me - Strimng to Long conversion error) ?